# How to make water treatment device hatch?

Tags: modeling

I have to draw a water treatment hatch, but since I'm not an expert in Blender  I'm asking for some help drawing it. Or do you know a tutorial where someone has made that kind of hatch already...

I need to model only RED COLORED part- I know how to model the BLACK PART...

[image: Troublesome part in RED]

Comment: are these grooves? It's not clear, please show some pictures if you have...

Answer (score 2):

This is not your final object but it's a way to get the basic shape:

- Put your image as a background image.
- In *Front Ortho*, create a plane, rotate it on the X axis, apply rotation, center it, mirror it on X and Z axis to make a symmetrical 2D copy of the blueprint.
- Switch to *Right Ortho* and extrude a bit.
- Select some of the vertical bars and extrude again.
- Create a UV sphere that follows the shape of the object.
- Boolean the 2 objects with the *Intersect* option.
- You have your basic mesh. Dissolve some edges, merge some vertices...
- Add some edge loops to sharp the edges. The knife tool will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: It's not much work to get from one to the other... but I saw holes where you see struts.. could be wrong.. as always..

Comment: oh sh*t you're right

Comment: ok, I've edited, I guess it's closer   ;)

Comment: nice result, too.